# Why does scipy.sparse.linalg.svds return a ValueError?

Tags: scipy, sparse-matrix, svd

Does anyone know that how to use **scipy.sparse** package to compute SVD on sparse matrix?

I know that I need to use **scipy.sparse.linalg.svds()**.

But I did as bellow:

```
from scipy.sparse import *
csr = csr_matrix(matrix) 
U, s, V = linalg.svds( csr )
```

I had this exception:

```
ValueError: matrix type must be 'f', 'd', 'F', or 'D'
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the matrix type from integers to doubles. If you initialize with constants, change one of the elements from integer format (`8`) to double format (`8.0`).